# Random Output result after if condition - python

Tags: python

I have two results want to show on the screen as below:

1. Print('That is an apple')
2. Print('This is an apple')

I want when user press any key , the result will be returned random by '1' or '2' as above.

How to do that ?

exp: I have code as below

```
user_response = input()
user_response=user_response.lower()
if(user_response == '1'):
    print('That is an apple')
    print('This is an apple')
```

I want to show randomly output result as above

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Please add the code that you have tried

Comment: Have a look at the [`random` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html).

Comment: Pls check as above

Answer (score 1):

In the following program, `n` is a random number between 0 and 1, so the condition `if round(n)` has 50% chance to be realized. I added an infinite loop, and you can stop the program by writing `stop`.

Please have a look :

```
import random

while True:
    i = input("Press any key...(write 'stop' to end)")
    if i == "stop":
        break
    n = random.random()
    if round(n):
        print('That is an apple')
    else:
        print('This is an apple')
```